# python class var will share between obj?

Tags: python, class, var

```
class cls():
    A = []

a = cls()
b = cls()
a.A.append("a")
print(b.A)
```

I run this on python 3.4.
but i see it print a stting "a".

I cant understand why this happen. a is different from b, but why they are share one var A?

Answer (score 2):

You've assigned a variable to the class. It only exists once for all instances (as long as you use it by reference, which `.append` does).

What you really want is an instance variable:

```
class cls():
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = []

a = cls()
b = cls()
a.A.append("a")
print(b.A)
```

Also, `cls` should not be used as the name of a class - use `CamelCase` names, and additionally `cls` should only be used with metaclasses or classmethods (you are unlikely to need either of these).

Comment: Thanks, I see now. variable inside class will stick in class itself.